# What is the next word in this sentence?

Tags: word, no-computers

**WARNING:** You could totally search online for this and find the answer. Note the [no-computer](/questions/tagged/no-computer) tag. Yes, you can cheat and I wouldn't know. However, that's not nearly as much fun and you'd be trading your eternal soul for internet points. Even if this is solved quickly by someone searching or recognizing it, I like the idea and think that something like it could be incorporated into future puzzles.

---

The words in this sentence follow a definite pattern. What is that pattern and what should the next word be? (There are, technically, many words that fit the pattern but there is an obvious "best" choice.)

> Man, I can’t - I shan’t! - formulate an anthem where the words comprise mnemonics (dreaded mnemonics) for ... ?

Comment: Eternal soul for Internet points!  Look at all these soulless puppets hehe

Comment: People at Puzzling.SE be like "shut up and take my soul!"

Comment: Related topic: Cadaeic.net/cadenza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> pi

The reason for this is:

> Taking the length of each word produces `3141592653589793` which are the first 16 digits of pi. The next digit is 2, so 'pi' is a natural final word for the sentence.

By the way, for what it's worth I hadn't seen this before

> I just started looking at the lengths of the words and after '314', I figured I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

> **pi**. The numerals just bother me always... even the dry anterior! Try to request something lower (zero) in numerary aptitude.

(I didn't look it up, but I *did* recognize it.)

Comment: OK, but why? Explanations always required on Puzzling.

Comment: 23846264338**3**27950288... You have an extra 1 (I) in your quote.

Answer (score 1):

> The words have the same number of letters of pi digits.
>  For example, Man has 3, I has 1, can't has 4.

I've already heard this from a math student (friend) few months ago. I think that the phrase is actually longer than the one you posted, since my friend claimed to know at least 100 words! I'm really not going to learn it, though!

Comment: At one point I had over 1,000 words memorized from the Cadaeic Cadenza.A ssimilar concept based on several different famous works. I've since forgotten most of it, but it was fun to recite when I knew it.